# Pagination not working in custom loop WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, pagination

Please help with pagination

I have code that works fine (functions.php)

```
function projects_custom_number_of_posts( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
    return;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'projects_custom_number_of_posts');
```

when I change to, pagination stops working

```
function projects_custom_number_of_posts( $query ) {
    $postsperpage = $query->get( 'posts_per_page' );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $postsperpage );
    return;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'projects_custom_number_of_posts');
```

It is necessary that the data is taken from the **'posts_per_page'**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('product_cat' => $cat, 'post_type' => 'product',  'posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged ); $query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, your 2nd block of code is just setting the `posts_per_page` to the current `posts_per_page`? You're also doing it for *every* query that gets run.

Comment: It is necessary for the pagination to work in loop product

Comment: Your `pre_get_posts` filter is pointless because you then replace the main query and use a secondary `WP_Query` in the template. Use `pre_get_posts` and only `pre_get_posts` and the problem will vanish. Your second code block is also a non-operation

Comment: Also note that WooCommerce is off topic here

Answer (score 0):

Having same problem. Ended up with the following codes

```
global $woocommerce_loop;
$woocommerce_loop['paged'] = (isset($woocommerce_loop['paged'])) ? $woocommerce_loop['paged'] : 1;
$woocommerce_loop['total'] = $custom_query->found_posts;
$woocommerce_loop['post_count'] = $custom_query->post_count;
$woocommerce_loop['per_page'] = $per_page;
$woocommerce_loop['total_pages'] = ceil($custom_query->found_posts/$per_page);
$woocommerce_loop['current_page'] = $args['paged'];
```